# Entity Framework 6 SQL Server Compact 4 Chinese character encoded incorrectly

Tags: entity-framework-6, encode

I have a Winform Entity Framework 6, SQL Server Compact 4 solution working fine with a method seeding initial data after database initialized. This solution was developed using Visual Studio 2013.

I installed Visual Studio 2015 and open the same solution, delete the database and run again, the database was initialized, however, the seed data created which has Chinese characters, are now saved to database with wrong encoding and become messy code.

When I type proper Chinese characters in SQL Server Compact database directly, the Winform application is showing them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio menu, click File and Advanced Save Options, save the file with the method that seed data with the Encoding option using "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature)" option.